# how to concatenate text from multiple rows in dataframe based on a specific structure

Tags: pandas, text, group-by, merge

I am going to merge multiple rows of a dataframe that has a specific structure of a text

For example, I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1, 'john', 'merge'),
    (1, 'smith,', 'merge'),
    (1, 'robert', 'merge'),
    (1, 'g', 'merge'),
    (1, 'owens,', 'merge'),
    (2, 'sarah will', 'OK'),
    (2, 'ali kherad', 'OK'),
    (2, 'david', 'merge'),
    (2, 'lu,', 'merge'),
    ], columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Merge'])
```

which is

```
  ID  Name    Merge
  1   john    merge
  1   smith,  merge
  1   robert  merge
  1   g       merge
  1   owens,  merge
  2   sarah will  OK
  2   ali kherad  OK
  2   david   merge
  2   lu,     merge
```

The goal is to have a datframe that merges the text in rows like this

```
    ID   Name  

0   1    john smith

1   1    robert g owens

2   2    sarah will

3   2    ali kherad

4   2    david lu
```

I found a way to create the column 'Merge' to know if I need to merge or not. Then I tried this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df[df['Merge']=='merge'].groupby(['ID','Merge'], axis=0)['Name'].apply(' '.join))


res = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',').explode()).reset_index().drop(['Merge'], axis=1)
```

First I groupby the names when the column 'Merge' is equal to 'merge'. I know this is not the best way because it only considers this condition but in my dataframe I should have the other rows when the column 'Merge' is equal to 'OK'.
Then I split by ','.

The result is

```
     ID   Name  

 0   1    john smith

 1   1    robert g owens

 2   1    

 3   2    david lu

 4   2
```

The other problem is that the order is not correct in my  real example when I have more than 4000 rows. How can I keep the order and merge the text when necessary?

Comment: what is your logic that seperate `john smith` and `robert g owens`?

Comment: @PandaKim there is a "," at the end of the entire name, so I know when I should end the name.

Comment: ok then remove ',' after seperate? or remain ','?

Comment: because I split then by ',' it will be removed which is okay

Answer (score 0):

make grouper for grouping

```
cond1 = df['Name'].str.contains('\,$') | df['Merge'].eq('OK')
g = cond1[::-1].cumsum()
```

`g`(chk reversed index)

```
8    1
7    1
6    2
5    3
4    4
3    4
2    4
1    5
0    5
dtype: int32
```

remove , and groupby by ID and g

```
out = (df['Name'].str.replace('\,$', '', regex=True)
       .groupby([df['ID'], g], sort=False).agg(' '.join)
       .droplevel(1).reset_index())
```

`out`

```
    ID  Name
0   1   john smith
1   1   robert g owens
2   2   sarah will
3   2   ali kherad
4   2   david lu
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I know what this means `cond1[::-1]`? When I try this I have the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: When error occurs, the first thing to do is to check if you followed it exactly before asking. if you exactly follow my code, error doesn't occues. chk `|` in my code.